# Cassandra return inconsistent result with secondary index

Tags: indexing, cassandra, datastax, cqlsh, nosql

Consider I have a columnFamily named PEOPLE. Suppose the columns are:

```
 1. id text (PRIMARY KEY)
 2. first_name text
 3. last_name text
 4. countries_visited Set<text>
```

I have created one secondary index on "countries_visited".
Now if I fire up a query like this:

select eid, first_name, countries_visisted from PEOPLE where countries_visited CONTAINS 'FRANCE';

So for a large number of records, it returns many records where countries_visited contains some other Strings (not "FRANCE").

I did use nodetool rebuild_index utility also, but I still get such result.

Is it the expected response ?

I am using:
CQL 3.2.1
Cassandra 2.1.11.908

Comment: Did you rebuild the index on ALL nodes?

Comment: Yes, I ran index rebuilding on all the nodes of the cluster. Infact when that didn't work, we ran nodetool repair on all node followed by index rebuilding just to be sure that all nodes are in sync and updated.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug?  I'd report an issue and see what they say

Comment: Can you post the output of a "DESCRIBE TABLE People;" call?

Comment: @0biwan can you post a describe table and an example of your query and result with a matching select to show the entire set data? Thank you.